# EF Core : The LINQ expression could not be translated. A ”where“ in ”select“

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```cs
var subProjects = await _projectRepository.Where(p => p.Id == id)
                .SelectMany(p => p.SubProjects
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        SubProject = x,
                        PdfCount = x.Files
                        .WhereIf(query.TaskId != null, f => f.ProjTask.Any(t => t.Id == query.TaskId))
                        .Count()
                    }))
                .ToListAsync();
```

> The LINQ expression 'f' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'f' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```cs
public class Project 
{
   //...other properties

   public virtual ICollection<SubProject> SubProjects { get; set; }
}

public class SubProjects 
{
   //...other properties
   
   public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
   //...other properties
   
   public virtual ICollection<ProjTask> ProjTask { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `.WhereIf`? Can you use that inside an expression? You'd probably have to remove that. You might be able to define `Expression<...> filter = (query.TaskId != null) ? f => f.ProjTask.Any(t => t.Id == query.TaskId) : f => true` outside the query, then use `.Where(filter)` inside the expression tree.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes,`WhereIf` is the matter, I defined the expression outside.But I should add `AsQueryable()` before `Where(filter)`, otherwise it can not be compiled. thks for ur help~